# Error trying to insert generic with Dapper.SimpleCRUD

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core, dapper, dapper-simplecrud

I'm trying to create a generic base class for my DataObjects like this :

```
public abstract class BaseDataObject<TDOType> where TDOType : class
{
    public static TDOType Get(Guid lObjectUUID, NpgsqlConnection conn)
    {
        return conn.Get<TDOType>(lObjectUUID);
    }

    public Guid Insert(NpgsqlConnection conn)
    {
        try
        {
            return conn.Insert<Guid, BaseDataObject<TDOType>>(this);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

My inherited class :

```
[Table("mytable")]
public class MyTable : BaseDataObject<MyTable>
{
    [Key]
    [Column("mytableuuid")]
    public Guid MyTableUUID { get; set; }
    [Column("clientuuid")]
    public Guid ClientUUID { get; set; }

}
```

When I call this method from an inherited object, I am thrown with the following message :

> 42601: syntax error at or near ")"

When I look at the statement in the exception that is being passed, it looks like this :

> {insert into "mytable" () values ()}

Even when I cast 'this', as follows, the result is the same :

```
try
{
    BaseDataObject<TDOType> q = this;
    return conn.Insert<Guid, BaseDataObject<TDOType>>(q);
}
```

It would appear that the generic function is not properly seeing the members of my inherited class. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not have postgresql database; I used SQL Server. But that should not matter.

Your problem is casting the generic object. Simply call the `conn.Insert` like below:

```
return conn.Insert<Guid, TDOType>(this as TDOType);
```

Note how I have cast the parameter to derived class than sending base class in to `conn.Insert` method. This way, SimpleCRUD can access the members of derived class.

In your code, it is not able to see the members of derived class. Hence, it cannot generate the query.

> {insert into "mytable" () values ()}

Look at the SQL query generated in your case as you post in question. It does not contain list of columns. Why? Because SimpleCRUD cannot see the properties of derived `MyTable` as you are sending in the base class `BaseDataObject<TDOType>`.

---

I used following database script:

```
CREATE TABLE [mytable]
(
    [mytableuuid]       [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] NOT NULL,
    [clientuuid]        [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] NOT NULL
)
```

Following is the model declaration:

```
[Table("mytable")]
public class MyTable : BaseDataObject<MyTable>
{
    [Key]
    [Column("mytableuuid")]
    public Guid MyTableUUID { get; set; }
    [Column("clientuuid")]
    public Guid ClientUUID { get; set; }

}

public abstract class BaseDataObject<TDOType> where TDOType : class
{
    public static TDOType Get(Guid lObjectUUID, SqlConnection conn)
    {
        return conn.Get<TDOType>(lObjectUUID);
    }

    public Guid Insert(SqlConnection conn)
    {
        try
        {
            return conn.Insert<Guid, TDOType>(this as TDOType);//<--Just change this call
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Following is how I call the `Insert` method:

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"connectionstring"))
{
    MyTable myTable = new MyTable();
    myTable.MyTableUUID = Guid.NewGuid();
    myTable.ClientUUID = Guid.NewGuid();
    myTable.Insert(conn); 
}
```